# JQuery Multi File event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

I have the following code in aspx

```
<input id="fileControl" type="file" class="multi" name="fileControl"/>
```

and

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var fileSelections = [];  
         $('#fileControl').MultiFile({

            onFileAppend: function () {
                //$('#F9-Log').append('<li>onFileAppend - '+value+'</li>')

                fileSelections.push(value);
            },
            onFileSelect: function () {

                fileSelections.push();
            },
            afterFileSelect: function () {

                fileSelections.push();
            },
            afterFileAppend: function () {

                fileSelections.push();
            }

        });

    });
```

I have added the following files as part of jQuery multifile plugin

```
jquery.MetaData.js
jquery.MultiFile.js
jquery.MultiFile.pack.js
```

But when I add or remove a file the events are not fired. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue and the problem is that if you want to subscribe to events, you can't set the class in the input element.

So, your input element should look like this:
`<input id="fileControl" type="file" name="fileControl"/>`

Then it should work.

I imagine this isn't an issue for you anymore, but in case this is ever needed by anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Just seen this.... have updated the documentation accordingly
http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/

I can hardly find the time to keep the docs up to date, but this is a huge issue (the reason behind most support queries I receive) so thanks for pointing it out!